# How does Hibernate work with @OneToOne and Cascade.ALL? (using Spring)

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data, one-to-one

I have a class Customer that has a OneToOne bidirectional relationship with a Subscription:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "customers")
public class Customer{
    @OneToOne(mappedBy="customer",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Subscription currentSubscription;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "subscriptions")
public class Subscription {

    @Id
    @Column(columnDefinition = "INT8",name="id", unique=true, nullable=false)
    @GeneratedValue(generator="gen")
    @GenericGenerator(name="gen", strategy="foreign", parameters=@Parameter(name="property", value="customer"))
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private Customer customer;
}
```

Now, when I create a customer with a subscription and call persist on the customer, it nicely saves the subscription as well into the database. However when I have already persisted a customer, and want to add a subscription, it fails with the following error:

> Caused by: org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: attempted
>   to assign id from null one-to-one property
>   [com.qmino.miredot.portal.domain.Subscription.customer]

I've written a test in order to explain what I want to achieve:

```
@Test
public void shouldCascadeUpdateSubscription(){
    Customer owner = customerRepository.save(CustomerMother.getCustomer(false));

    Subscription subscription = SubscriptionBuilder.create()
            .setBillingDayOfMonth(LocalDate.now().getDayOfMonth())
            .setSubscriptionPlan(subscriptionPlan)
            .build();

    subscription.setCustomer(owner);
    owner.setCurrentSubscription(subscription);

    customerRepository.save(owner);

    Customer result = customerRepository.findOne(owner.getId());
    assertThat(result.getCurrentSubscription(),is(notNullValue()));
    assertThat(result.getCurrentSubscription().getId(),is(result.getId()));
}
```

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: do you say entities are linked bidirectional way? It doesn't look like. Your Subsribtion doesn't have a customer. so 'mappedBy="customer" ' is redundant.

Comment: My bad, made an error. It should be correct now.

Comment: subscription.setAccountDetails(owner); Why don't you follow EJB specification? Hibernate should have a proper setters/getters. So instead of "setAccoundDetails" should be "setCustomer"/"getCustomer"

Comment: Again an error, I mistakenly typed the wrong class, and forgot the setter as well. My apologies.

Comment: So parameters=@Parameter(name="property", value="accountDetails" also should be a customer? Please fix all typos

Comment: Sorry, the typos are strong today. All of them should be fixed now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75090/discussion-between-denewout-and-ernusc).

Answer (score 2):

Cascade here is not the problem, Cascade indicates the action to be done by entity when deleted or updated. What is correct if you want to save complete entity. But for that, you need to have the correct data, your message suggest it tries to update the `Customer` entity but it founds an empty `AccountDetails`, so in order to correctly fetch the other entities, you need to add `FecthType.EAGER`, to get all attributes of mapped entities.

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy="customer",cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER))
```

Comment: I should clarify, the error that I get, occurs on the second save on owner. I'm only getting a customer near the end of my test, the problem occurs before that.

Comment: Downside of a FetchType.EAGER is the fact that you are going to have separate select queries for relations. Might be a problem sometimes.